# TortoiseGit - How to perform a git reset --hard <by reading the commit hash from a file>

Tags: git, tortoisegit

How to perform a `git reset --hard` - by reading the commit hash from a file

Comment: You should post your code, what did you tried?

Comment: I am using the command - "git reset --hard a7abda785", i would like to read this (a7abda785) commit hash from a file.

Comment: What would the file look like? Would it just contain a single hash or a list of hashes?

Comment: The text file will have just one hash

Answer (score 2):

1. Open `Reset` dialog

   - Open Log Message dialog
   - Right click on **any** commit
   - Click `Reset "xxx" to this...`
     [image]
2. Reset Hard [sha-1]

   - Copy the sha-1 value from your file
   - Paste it into **Commit text filed**
   - Click the `Hard` option
   - Push `OK` button
     [image]
3. Refresh the Log dialog

---

BTW, if the file is `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, you can just view that commit by this way:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're on Windows because of the TortoiseGit in the title.

Given a **hash.txt** with just "a7abda785" as its contents (or any hash for that matter), you can run this batch file to do `git reset` using the hash from **hash.txt**:

```
@echo off

set /p HASH= < hash.txt
git reset --hard %HASH%
```

The `/p` [sets the variable by prompting the user for input](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html), which we automatically provide by redirecting the contents of the file.

With this script, you can include:

1. Putting a different hash into **hash.txt**
   (I assume you are using some other command or script to write the hash to the text file)
2. Skipping `git reset` if the hash is invalid (i.e. empty)

Comment: Thank you very much.. this is exactly what i needed.